# The first character of command is being removed automatically by the shell

Tags: shell-script, gnuplot

I have a simple shell script to copy certain data file from one directory into the current working directory and I plot this file along with another file in the working directory using gnuplot. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
SILVACO_DIR="/home/pbaikadi/my_silvaco/atlas/mat1-mat2-hetero/"
LATEST_DAT_FILE=$(ls -t $SILVACO_DIR|head -1)
FILE_PATH=$(readlink -f $SILVACO_DIR$LATEST_DAT_FILE)
cp -v $FILE_PATH .
FILE=$(ls -t $PWD|head -1)
echo "$FILE"
sed -i '1,4d' "$FILE"
awk '{$1=$1*1000;print $1>"temp1.dat";print $2>"temp2.dat"}' "$FILE"
paste temp1.dat temp2.dat > "$FILE"
rm temp1.dat temp2.dat
gnuplot <<EOF -persist
set key font "Helvetica,15"
set tics font "Helvetica,10"
set xlabel 'Position (in nm)' font "Helvetica,15" offset 0,0,0
set ylabel 'Conduction Band Energy in eV' font "Helvetica,15" offset 4,0,0
set title 'Conduction Band Cutline along Y and between the gates' font "Helvetica,15"
plot 'cond_cutline_y_between_gates.txt' w linespoints title "With PETSc"
#replot "$FILE" w linespoints title "With Silvaco"
EOF
rm $FILE
```

The problem I am facing is that the first character of any command before the EOF delimiter is being removed. I tried a work around for this by having # as the first character of the command and it works but I would like to understand the mistake I am committing in the original code. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: You say the first character of each line is missing. _When_ is it missing? Is it when you view the file in the shell with e.g. `less`, or do you get error messages about `cho` (for `echo`) not being a valid command etc.?  Is the script a Unix text file or a DOS text file from Windows?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is missing for any command in the line before the EOF delimiter. Following your example, I get error about `cho` when the actual command to be executed is `echo`. The script is a DOS text file from Windows. I use dos2unix to convert from DOS format to UNIX format.

Comment: @prananna, could you try to to reduce that script to a smaller one that still shows the same problem and [edit] into your question? Preferably as small as you can make it. On a quick look, it seems the `sed`s and `awk`s etc. there shouldn't be the cause, so they're a bit of a distraction. Also, can you please show how exactly you run the script, and what the output is?

Comment: What happens if you create a temporary file, say `gnuplot.in`, via a heredoc, and then invoke `gnuplot gnuplot.in`?